# TreeList field cannot be updated

Tags: sitecore-client, content-editor

TreeListType field is not getting updated when selecting value from left pane to right pane.
Updated the value to display the raw value. But it is not updated.
The value was updated or deleted with DBbrowser. But it is not updated.
Other fields with the same content have been updated.

If anyone met the same problem, please tell me how it was solved?

Version：Sitecore Experience Platform 8.1 rev. 160519 (8.1 Update-3)

Comment: Please clarify your question and add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. it is not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: As you mention altering the field with dbbrowser - did you clear caches? Tried restarting?

Comment: When an item is selected from the left window in the field of TreeListType, it is set to the right window.
Saving an item sets the selected item in the right pane,
Even if saved, it is not set in the right window.
There are two environments, a production environment and a verification environment, but only the production environment has occurred.
So it may be an environment-dependent problem.

Thank you very much. Clear the cache.

Comment: I restarted IIS and cleared the cache, but it has not been resolved.

Comment: Are there any errors during save? Do you have custom processors in item:saving, item:saved? I wonder if they are erring silently and causing the save not to be committed.

Comment: It seems that both VersionedFields table and UnversionedFields table have data of the same item and the same field.
I will continue to investigate why this record was created.
It may be related to the Japanese environment.
Thank you for your comment.